# Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitMQ binder, how to apply @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-data-mongodb, spring-cloud-stream

I have a [Spring Cloud Stream](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) application that receives events from [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) using the [Rabbit Binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit). My application can be summarized as this:

```
@Transactional
@StreamListener(MySink.SINK_NAME)
public void processEvents(Flux<Event> events) {
       // Transform events and store them in MongoDB using 
       // spring-boot-data-mongodb-reactive
       ...
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem that `@Transactional` works with Spring Cloud Stream (or at least that's my impression) since if there's an exception when writing to MongoDB the event seems to have already been ack:ed to RabbitMQ and the operation is not retried.

Given that I want to achieve basically the same functionality as when using the `@Transactional` around a function with [spring-amqp](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp):

1. Do I have to manually ACK the messages to RabbitMQ when using Spring
   Cloud Stream with the Rabbit Binder?
2. If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.

1. Transactions are not required for acknowledging messages
2. Reactor-based `@StreamListener` methods are invoked exactly once, just to set up the `Flux` so `@Transactional` on that method is meaningless - messages then flow through the flux so anything pertaining to individual messages has to be done within the context of the flux.
3. Spring Transactions are bound to the thread - Reactor is non-blocking; the message will be acked at the first handoff.

Yes, you would need to use manual acks; presumably on the result of the mongodb store operation. You would probably need to use `Flux<Message<Event>>` so you would have access to the channel and delivery tag headers.